# Migrating from multiple WordPress instances to one WordPress MU?

Tags: linux, mysql, wordpress, migration, wordpress-mu

In reference to my [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/116032/alternative-to-multiple-wordpress-installs-and-not-using-wordpress-mu), wherein it appears the best way of handling multiple instances of WordPress will be to use MU (even across multiple domains, etc) - I'm looking for a way to migrate multiple individual WordPress instances to one wp-mu installation.

Looking through the [WPMU Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU), I don't see anything - perhaps I've just missed it, though.

Has anyone on serverfault done such a migration, and, if so, could you shed some light on how to approach it?

I'm running on CentOS 4 with MySQL 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress (single) and MU are merging soon, so I suspect it will be easy to import individual installs into MU:  [WordPress Development Updates](http://wpdevel.wordpress.com/).